# How to not upload standard log output to Allure report

Tags: python, pytest, allure

Any time I log some information with Python logger I see in Allure Report "log" attach that Allure make automatically. Is is standard output. Any string in my code  `logging.info('some info')` produced another string in standard output which automatically attach to Allure Report with name "log".

How to avoid this or delete this log file from final Allure Report?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtrKg.png)

Answer (score -1):

To prevent Allure from including standard output logs as attachments in reports, you can:

Configure your Python logger to write logs to a file instead of standard output.

Redirect the standard output to /dev/null or another location to suppress it, but note that this option will affect all standard output, not just the Python logger logs.

Explore configuring Allure or your testing framework integration to customize log attachment handling.

Filter unwanted log messages so they are not written to the logger when they are not needed in Allure reports.

Comment: Yes, I set ```log.basicConfig(filename=f'{os.getcwd()}/log', filemode='w', level=log.INFO)```, but it has no result. Log-file anyway attach to Allure

Comment: It's possible that Allure is capturing all files from the test environment as attachments. In this case, you might need to modify your Allure configuration to exclude specific files or directories from being attached

Comment: If I understood correct there are not a special setting or config to do that. Only by modifying allure code or clean allure files in source directory where allure attach this files from.